# Game theory and the Reverse mathematics theme

Tags: nash-equilibrium, reverse-math, second-order-logic

After having studied carefully Simpson's book SOSOA (Subsystems of second order arithmetic) I've naturally arrived at the question about the connection of Game theory with Reverse mathematics. Is there such a thing? Results such as this is of interest for me: any finite normal form game has a Nash Equilibrium iff $\textsf{WKL}_0$ holds over $\textsf{RCA}_0$. It is just an example, I do not claim it is true.

Comment: This, on the other hand, is a nice question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extensive body of research on games (specifically *determinacy principles*) and reverse mathematics. Just to mention a few results:

- WKL$_0$ is equivalent to clopen determinacy for games on $\{0,1\}$ (= "Finite-length, finite-option games have winning strategies").
- ATR$_0$ is equivalent to both clopen determinacy on $\omega$ and to open determinacy on $\omega$ - this is due to Steel.

  - Incidentally, clopen and open determinacy for games on $\mathbb{R}$ are *not* equivalent in higher reverse mathematics; this was initially [proved by me](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/transfinite-recursion-in-higher-reverse-mathematics/25B725E71B403A4D4DFB950C903234FE) via forcing, then shortly after given a much better proof by [Hachtman](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~shac/reverse.pdf) via fine structure theory, and apparently there's another proof by [Sato](http://home.inf.unibe.ch/~sato/) (although it hasn't appeared yet) via proof theory.

(From now on, games are on $\omega$.)

- $\Pi^1_1$-CA$_0$ is equivalent to $\Sigma^0_1\wedge\Pi^0_1$-determinacy.
- A very fine-grained analysis has been conducted by Nemoto, e.g. [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.200710081).
- At the higher determinacy levels, there is a tight analysis by Montalban/Shore (see e.g. this paper); it's a bit technical, however, due to their proof that no true $\Sigma^1_4$ sentence can imply $\Delta^1_2$-CA$_0$ (in particular, full $\Sigma^1_1$ determinacy doesn't imply $\Delta^1_2$-CA$_0$), which renders straightforward reversals impossible.

  - In particular, they show that $(i)$ for each $n$, Z$_2$ proves $n$-$\Pi^0_3$ determinacy, but $(ii)$ $\Delta^0_4$-determinacy isn't provable in Z$_2$ (this refuted an earlier claim by Martin).
- An astronomically less important, but still in my mind neat, example (and plugging my own work): determinacy for Banach-Mazur games for Borel subspaces of Baire space is equivalent to ATR$_0$ and to Banach-Mazur determinacy for *analytic* subspaces *(I got the lower bounds, the upper bounds being essentially due to Steel)*; meanwhile, determinacy for $\Sigma^1_2$-Banach-Mazur games is independent of ZFC, so there could be some really cool stuff here (but I haven't been able to tease it out).

---

Moving from determinacy to equilibria, I'm less familiar with this but [Yamazaki/Peng/Peng](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/CTFM/CTFM2015/slides/TYamazaki.pdf) showed that Glicksberg's theorem ("every continuous game has a mixed Nash equilibrium") is equivalent to ACA$_0$. See also [Weiguang Peng's thesis](https://tohoku.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=repository_action_common_download&item_id=123607&item_no=1&attribute_id=18&file_no=1).

In general, equilibria seem to have not been studied as much as determinacy principles in reverse math; I suspect this is because of the hugely important role determinacy principles play in set theory.

Possibly also of interest, but not strictly reverse math:

- The complexity-theoretic difficulty of finding Nash equilibria has been studied by several people, e.g. [Daskalakis/Goldberg/Papadimitriou](https://people.csail.mit.edu/costis/simplified.pdf).
- Equilibria have been studied from the perspective of Weirauch reducibility by [Pauly](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.429.8129&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
- [Tanaka](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2012/459459/) looked at equilibria in a constructive context.

Comment: Interestingly, googling '"reverse mathematics" "game theory"' doesn't give many relevant hints, so I suspect that a lot of game theory hasn't been so analyzed yet.

Comment: Your last comment is precisely what I originally intended to say. It would be a good research program to analyze this.

Comment: Also my question targeted at **non**-set theoretcial (i.e. classical, finitary and matrix/tree) game theory.

Comment: @user122424 Incidentally, I believe it's folklore that Zermelo's determinacy theory (every game on $\omega$ with bounded finite length is determined) is equivalent to ACA$_0^+$ ("for all $n$ and $X$ the $n$th jump of $X$ exists).

Comment: Do you have a citation for the result that WKL0 is equivalent to clopen determinacy for games on {0,1}? I can see how the proof would go but I need a reference for something I am writing up

Comment: @AlyxCaptain I think it's folklore, but I'll do a quick check later today.